# dots on my laptop's screen

Tags: windows-7, display

I see weird dots on my laptop's screen since I bought it. I have attached the screenshots. I mark them in blue circles. My system is acer 5820tg, windows7, latest drivers.

[image]
[image]

How can I get rid of them? Or at least I can google about them if I knew the technical name of them.

Comment: See [Defective pixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_pixel)

Comment: Screenshots show what video card sends to screen, not what the screen actually displays, so those images look totally fine. Please describe what those dots look like or show us photos.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pictures, I can't see anything strange on them, certainly no dots. As suggested, this is most likely dead or defective pixels, as they wont show up on a screen capture.

There is a very small chance that this can be fixed using software, else you would have to take it back to where you bought it and see if they will replace it.

The software I've used it JScreenFix. Link: http://www.jscreenfix.com/

Somtimes this works, but most of the times the pixels are completely trashed and only a replacement would fix it.